# How can you access the packet information in a JpCap Packet

Tags: java, networking, packet, packet-sniffers, jpcap

How can I pull relevant packet information from a JpCap packet? I am trying to find the source/destination ip and port. So far I have tried string parsing the Packet's toString() method, but that seems brutish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cast the Packet object to the correct type of Packet i think.

So something like:

```
TCPPacket p = (TCPPacket)packet;

// Get the tcp src and dest ports
int destPort = p.dst_port;
int srcPort = p.src_port;

// Get the src and dest IP addresses from the IP layer
InetAddress destIp = p.dst_ip;
InetAddress srcIp = p.src_ip;
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved me so much ugly parsing

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good [example](http://sourceforge.net/p/arp-spoofing/wiki/SamplePage/) about accessing packets information using Jpcap Packet